# cURL API Commands

Tags: api, curl

I have a question about API's and cURL. I'm not sure if this is all Python, but I am trying to access JSON data using an API, but the server isn't as easy as grabbing the data with an XMLRequest... The support team gave me this line of code:

```
curl -k -s --data "api_id=xxxx&api_key=xxxx&time_range=today&site_id=xxxxx"
https://my.incapsula.com/api/stats/v1
```

And I have no idea what this even means because all the API requests I've been making was just as easy as using a link and parsing through it with some JavaScript. Can anyone break the *-k -s --data* for me or point me in a right tutorial?

(NOT PYTHON; Sorry guys...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right tutorial is [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl).

> **-k/--insecure**
>
> (SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers. All SSL connections are attempted to be made secure by using the CA certificate bundle installed by default. This makes all connections considered "insecure" fail unless *-k/--insecure* is used.
>
> See this online resource for further details: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> **-s/--silent**
>
> Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages. Makes Curl mute.

As for `--data`, well, it specify the data you are sending to the server.

This question is (for now) not related to Python at all, but eventually to shell scripting.

Comment: So does this mean I need to be in a Linux based environment to develop a request for the JSON data (since shell scripts, iirc, are done mostly in Linux based environments)?

Comment: `curl` is primarily used in shell scripts are which are usually in a POSIX environment (GNU/Linux, BSD, Apple, ...), but the tool also works on Microsoft. Choose a language and platform to develop your tool that suit your needs, might be PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby, PowerShell, C#, Lisp, whatever... I think the support team gave you the curl command because it is widely available, documented and the request is easy to port to another language (event without using the libcurl).

Comment: Yeah I had a friend help me out a little bit and I actually finally got to see the json file, but on my Mac terminal. I heard that there were Windows workarounds, which I will probably have to do, but I'm probably going to end up using shell scripts to pipe the JSON file and have JavaScript to parse out the info I need. Big thanks!